# Android arraylist.get getting the wrong value using an index

Tags: android, arrays, get

I'm at my wit's end with this one!  Here's some of my code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> indices;
int total = 10;

for(int c = 0; c < total; ++c)
    {
        score.add(c);
    }

indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(total);
    for(int c = 0; c < total; ++c)
    {
        indices.add(c);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(indices);

    rando1 = indices.get(0);

int currentScore;
currentScore = score.get(indices.get(rando1));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "score location should be: " + rando1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "score location is: " + currentScore, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The toasts were to help me see what's going on.  For some reason, no matter what I try, the rando1 and the currentScore will almost always be different numbers.

This is baffling me because I use rando1 on a number of other arrays (string arrays), and it always gets the correct items from the other arrays.

My question is why doesn't this get the same index item (the integer at whatever index) from the integer array as it does from the other string arrays.  I've tried isolating just this code.  I've tried changing various things.  I've done a lot of testing.  And the searches don't turn up anything too specific (but I've tried what I found there as well).

Desired output of the toasts: "score location should be: 3", "score location is: 3"

Actual output: "score location should be: 3", "score location is: 5" (replace 5 with any other number, because there's never a set pattern between what it should be and what it is).

Comment: because you've shuffled the `indices`?

Comment: I shuffle them, and then use the first number of the shuffle for various things.  That's definitely not the problem, as everything else matches the index.  Is it not possible to pull a specific integer out of an array of integers?  I mean, does the get() get(confused)?  That's the only thing I can see being possible here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to get a random element ArrayList.

```
Random r = new Random();
currentScore = score.get(r.nextInt(score.size()))
```

If you want to the output, as you have, then change the following line:

```
currentScore = score.get(rando1);
```

Comment: I would love to do this, but I need a non-repeating list to form, which is why I'm using shuffle.  I'm actually pulling the first 6 values out of the indices after I shuffle, then using those values to pull strings from two string arrays and an integer out of this integer array.  But it keeps pulling out the wrong integer!

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Add the output. (desired and actual)

Comment: I added them at the bottom of my post.  And am adding a couple other items momentarily just for clarity.

Comment: I feel like I should delete this question because the answer was so obvious...  As I went to update my question, I noticed the answer STARING ME IN THE FACE!!  I knew it was going to be something stupid.  Sorry to waste your time!  (I'm embarrassed at how long this took me to figure out).  Also, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Everything is fine. The 15's reputation took off my ban on the site. (I could not ask questions). By the way, you have a little reputation. You should be responsible to not get a lock.